# XYZ and arcgis Esri in openlayers 6

Tags: esri, xyz

Does anybody know what parameters are required to use this source
in openlayers 6 XYZ layer
with projection EPSG:4326

https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}

thanks

Comment: Check this [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri-4326-512.html), you just need to change the url to the map you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the help

this source is simpler ( but different ) than the source from the example and has a better resolution

but this Source doesn't need the tileUrlFunction ( just pass the url )

you need 
sphericalMercator true
wrapX true
and
tileSize 256

the same options could be used for

https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Shaded_Relief/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}